# Map of vectors to vector of maps

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure

I would like to replace this structure,

```
{:a [1 2 .. 3] :b [1 2 .. 3] :c [1 2 3 ..]}
```

to this.

```
[{:a 1 :b 1 c 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2} {:a 3 :b 3 :c 3} ...]
```

Number of keys is not specified.

Comment: Are we assuming that each vector in the original map is identical? i.e. they are all `[1 2 3 .. ]`?

Comment: No, in each vector is _random_ data, but number of objects in each vector is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, very ugly solution, but it can explain what I need.

```
#(map (fn [line] 
       (zipmap (keys %) line)) 
     (partition (count (keys %)) 
                (apply interleave (vals %))))
```

If anyone could simplify this, it would be great.

EDIT:

```
#(map (fn [vs]
     (zipmap (keys %) vs))(apply map vector (vals %)))
```

Comment: nice, I got similar solution

Comment: Style suggestion: it's normal to use the `#( ... )` form on the smallest scale: `(fn [mm] (map #(zipmap (keys mm) %) (apply map vector (vals mm))))`

Answer (score 0):

```
(def z (sorted-map :a [1 2 3 4] :b ["a" "b" "c" "d"] :c [:i :j :k :l]))

(defn x []
  (let [k (repeat (keys z))
        v (apply map vector (vals z))]
    (map zipmap k v)))


user> (x)
({:c :i, :b "a", :a 1} {:c :j, :b "b", :a 2} {:c :k, :b "c", :a 3} {:c :l, :b "d", :a 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
   #(mapv 
      (partial apply merge) 
      (map val 
         (group-by (comp  second first) 
         (for [[x y] % z y] (hash-map x z)))))

;=>[{:a 1, :c 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :c 2, :b 2} {:a 3, :c 3, :b 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [x  {1 [:a :b :c], 2 [:d :e :f], 3 [:g :h :i]}
      k (vec (keys x))
      r (map #(apply merge %)
             (apply map (fn [ & a]
                          (merge (map-indexed
                                  (fn [idx v] {(k idx) v}) a))) (vals x)))]
      (println r))
```

Comment: you can define `k` as `(keys x)`

Comment: @noisesmith Yes, thanks. Decided I might as well present the complete code.